# Node.js websocket error "Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL"

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ubuntu-server, total.js

Application work fine on localhost .but when its connect to server it getting error.
I connect server through port 22

This is the error

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
at listen (net.js:1064:10)
at net.js:1146:9
at dns.js:72:18
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

Any Help !!!

-update-

i run `netstat -tulpn | grep 22`

Result:

```
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      683/sshd
 tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      683/sshd
```

but i run `netstat -tulpn | grep 80`

Nothing Display.

Any Help.is this server fault?

running `netstat -nlt`

```
     Active Internet connections (only servers)
     Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
     tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5902          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
     tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
     tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Running `netstat -anp | grep :80`

```
     tcp        1      0 162.243.145.226:60728   91.189.94.25:80         CLOSE_WAIT  1726/ubuntu-geoip-p
     tcp        1      0 162.243.145.226:47842   74.125.239.148:80       CLOSE_WAIT  8104/epiphany-brows
     tcp        1      0 162.243.145.226:60727   91.189.94.25:80         CLOSE_WAIT  1417/ubuntu-geoip-p
     tcp        1      0 162.243.145.226:58818   198.41.30.199:80        CLOSE_WAIT  8104/epiphany-brows
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @ravi - I tried to connect app with server.app working fine on localhost.but when connecting server it give these errors.

`https://github.com/totaljs/examples/tree/master/angularjs-websocket`  this is the project.

Comment: it would be easier if you just show us your server file code. And if you're using `https://github.com/totaljs/examples/tree/master/angularjs-websocket` directly w/o any modifications then the default port they use is 8000. Try connecting to the public IP of server, like, `http://<SERVER-IP>:8000`. And for testing for port use`lsof -i :8000`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a used port. You must change a port or you must kill a process which is listening on a port. Open terminal and write (example): `lsof -i :22` or `lsof -i :80` or `lsof -i :8000` and `kill PID` of the process.

---

How to change the listening **PORT** in total.js?

1. in */app/config* or */app/config-release* or */app/config-debug*:

```
default-ip       : 127.0.0.1
default-port     : 8000
```

or

```
// For e.g. Heroku
default-ip       : auto
default-port     : auto
```

2. if exist files: *release.js* or *debug.js*:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var options = {};

// options.ip = "127.0.0.1";
// options.port = parseInt(process.argv[2]);
options.port = 8000;
```

3. if exists only *index.js*

```
// for development:
require('total.js').http('debug', { port: 8000 });

// or for production:
require('total.js').http('release', { port: 8000 });
```

Thanks and documentation: http://docs.totaljs.com

Answer (score 8):

Just saw this today. User had commented out `127.0.0.1 localhost` in their `/etc/hosts` file, and another network service was resolving `localhost` to a different IP address *not* associated with the user's machine.

Solution was to add this line to `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are using a Unix based OS, if that is the case then you can't use any port below 1024 without sudo access.

Also before digging too deep check that the listening port is not being used by any other process.

**A quick fix (for development only):**

- `sudo node file.js`
  or
- `server.listen(3000); // any number > 1024`

**For production (never run node on production with root access.)**

you have to map the listening port (ex:3000) to 80 using ip tables

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Comment: Thanks For answering.but im using windows os.my server only ubuntu.
any help for windows :)

Comment: i run your ip tableing command on server but nothing happen..something wrong in my server?

Comment: @mahmoud-mahfouz   -  Then can you provide solution.please

Comment: EADDRNOTAVAIL (Address Not Available) is a Linux error. it means that TCP connection cant be accomplished. this happens when the ports are in use or not accessible (ex: ports < 1024). to check a port is in use or not use `netstat -pn |grep :PORT_NUMBER`, and to use a port < 1024 either use sudo or port forward the port of the app (ex: 3000 to 80) using iptables

Comment: @Sameera I think you are asking about how to upload files to the server. if that is the case then: you can use FTP (https://filezilla-project.org/), or you can add the code to git and pull it on server.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only reaching this error after many requests, you might want to check your port range settings and adjust them. There is also TCP timeout settings, such as FIN_WAIT that can keep connections open for longer than expected.

`sysctl -a | grep net` should show all network connection settings.

`sysctl -a | grep port` for port range settings.

`sysctl -a | grep keep` for tcp wait settings.

[See here](https://serverfault.com/questions/216956/how-to-check-tcp-timeout-in-linux-macos) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573390/how-to-view-and-edit-the-ephemeral-port-range-on-linux)(mac [here](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-kernel-limits.html)) for a little more detail/advice on what the settings are.

If you are going to modify settings, I would suggest that you first copy `/etc/sysctl.conf` to something like `/etc/sysctl.conf.bak` and then modify the setting in that file. They can be adjusted via the command-line but that is temporary and resetting them can be a mess.

You probably don't want to do this in production.

Additional docs:

https://ma.ttias.be/linux-increase-ip_local_port_range-tcp-port-range/

https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/sysctl-conf/

Answer (score 1):

Port 22 is reserved for ssh and on the list of well known ports, please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)#Common_port_numbers

I would recommend you to run node apps for development on ports 8000-9000, but you can use any from the registered ports range.

Comment: how can i change my ports?
putty didnt allow me to connect port 80

Comment: with putty you connect on port 22 as it is the ssh port, but your node app should use a different port.

Comment: yes.my node app use port 80.
but its keep getting this error

Comment: what is your output from "netstat -tulpn | grep :80" enter this into the ssh console

Comment: please provide some sourcecode in your question, i cant help you further without it

Comment: i used this example to connect with my server ip and port.

https://github.com/totaljs/examples/tree/master/angularjs-websocket