# How to view and edit the ephemeral port range on Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, networking, network-programming, unix-socket

In my Linux system ephemeral port range  is showing different ranges as follows

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range 
32768  61000
```



```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500
```

Which will be the effective ephemeral port range in my system?

Comment: Only output of /proc files or sysctl tool will show the actual effective port range. /etc/sysctl.conf may or may not be loaded on boot. In your case it does not match so it is either not loaded or overwritten. /proc tells the truth (so should `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Following command will list the ephemeral port range in Linux system

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
```

If we don't want to reboot, after editing /etc/sysctl.conf file if we execute following command it will be effective.

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf .
```

The truth of the matter of effective range is output of

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
```

as mentioned by eckes in comment.

Comment: For me on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo) the command sysctl doesn't exist. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @junkie Did you try as `sudo sysctl.... ` ?