# What does multiple KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS mean when we have only one broker, vs when we have many?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am learning Kafka and trying to use it with docker. I'm confused looking at the docker-compose files, so I wanted to ask my questions here.

In most examples, I see a config like this:

```
broker:
   image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.3.1
   ...
   ports:
       - "29192:29092" 
       - "9192:9092"
   environment:
        ...
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```

I wanted to understand a few things related to this:

1. Is there a particular convention for using 5-digit (ex: 29092) port **vs** 4-digit (ex: 9092) ports?
2. Is there a specific relation between the number of configured brokers to the number of listeners mentioned in `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`? [In some places, like confluent's own example](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/6.0.0-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml), I see only one broker, but multiple `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`. What does that mean?
3. Also, in the same confluent example mentioned above, there is a listener: `PLAINTEXT://broker:29092` in `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`, but we do not have any broker or zookeeper configured at port 29092, so what is that doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` is a list of addresses to a particular broker. When a client first contacts the broker acting as "bootstrap server" it will get in return the addresses of brokers responsible for each partition.
Clients will need different addresses depending on which network they come from. The "bootstrap server", knowing "advertised listeners" for all the brokers, will choose the appropriate addresses to return based on which of its own listeners the client used to connect.

**TL;DR**

Source: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

---

> 1. Is there a particular convention for using 5-digit (ex: 29092) port vs 4-digit (ex: 9092) ports?

I believe the only convention is 9092 as the broker port. When multiple ports are needed people seem to use a variation of it. I've seen 9093, and now 29092.

> 2. Is there a specific relation between the number of configured brokers to the number of listeners mentioned in
>    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS? In some places, like confluent's own
>    example, I see only one broker, but multiple
>    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS. What does that mean?

There is no relation. Each broker has it's own `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` list. It refers to that particular broker only, not the other brokers.

When a client connects to kafka, it first talks to a broker acting as "bootstrap server". That broker will then respond with metadata including the addresses of particular brokers the client should reach when talking about particular partitions. These addresses will depend on which network the client is coming from. E.g. `localhost:9092` for clients in the docker host vs. `broker:29092` for clients within docker network. That's why one broker can have multiple `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`.

> 3. Also, in the same confluent example mentioned above, there is a listener: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092 in KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS, but
>    we do not have any broker or zookeeper configured at port 29092, so
>    what is that doing?

In the confluent example, that `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` line is actually configuring the broker to listen on 29092. All clients internal to docker are using this port to reach the broker.

Btw, 29092 is not in the `ports:` mapping above as it's only used by internal clients (doesn't need to be exposed to a host port). Only 9092 needs to be exposed outside of docker in this example.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a particular convention for using 5-digit (ex: 29092) port vs
> 4-digit (ex: 9092) ports?

To avoid getting a port conflict at run time of an application, you should configure ports for an application out of ephemeral port range of server. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573390/how-to-view-and-edit-the-ephemeral-port-range-on-linux) question and answer to find , how can you find or modify the ephemeral port range. So the convention is, find a port out of ephemeral port range and use as an application port.

> Is there a specific relation between the number of configured brokers
> to the number of listeners mentioned in KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS? In
> some places, like confluent's own example, I see only one broker, but
> multiple KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS. What does that mean?

Kafka can be deployed in a cluster within multiple nodes. Each node has its own IP and port number within `config/server.properties` file. Number of listeners and advertised listeners depends on the number of nodes within your Kafka deployment.

> Also, in the same confluent example mentioned above, there is a
> listener: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092 in KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS, but
> we do not have any broker or zookeeper configured at port 29092, so
> what is that doing?

Kafka need a Zookeeper deployment to manage its cluster management, irrespective of there is only one node of Kafka or multiple nodes. But it can use any port, and there is no hard and fast rule to use 29092 port.

Comment: What you answered is a bit vague, even though i think the questions were pretty to-the-point .

Answer (score 0):

To clarify your questions:

> 1. Is there a particular convention for using 5-digit (ex: 29092) port **vs** 4-digit (ex: 9092) ports?

Common values seen in documentation are sequences like `9092, 9093, 9094` and  `9092, 19092, 29092` etc. While technically speaking they're arbitrary, the sequence usually matches up with a broker id.

- A possible example:
- Broker 1: `19092`
- Broker 2: `19093`
- Broker 3: `19094`

Since services like databases usually have a single socket endpoint which clients connect to, there is usuaully a highly recognizable port number as the default, which then other services typically avoid using.

When I installed Kafka recently I saw port conflicts with `9092` on one machine, so I chose a different sequence of numbers starting from `19092`.

2. Is there a specific relation between the number of configured brokers to the number of listeners mentioned in `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`? [In some places, like confluent's own example](https://medium.com/@fintechdevlondon/kafka-listeners-and-advertised-listeners-what-are-they-and-what-do-they-do-9b004e2eb93d), I see only one broker, but multiple `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`. What does that mean?

You can have multiple addresses for every broker. A broker might have an ip based address and a dns based address. If dns isn't working for some reason, the broker may still be contactable using the ip address.

As far as I am aware, a broker *shouldn't usually have the address for other brokers as part of its* `advertised.listeners` string. If you see this, it's probably a bad setup. (but there might be some legitimate reason for it, maybe proxying ... ?)

3. Also, in the same confluent example mentioned above, there is a listener: `PLAINTEXT://broker:29092` in `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`, but we do not have any broker or zookeeper configured at port 29092, so what is that doing?

Some possible reasons for this:

- It **might** be because Kafka is running in a Docker container which exposes port `29092`, but where the Kafka process is actually running on a different (internal to docker) port. Clients are expected to connect to the address `broker:29092` for **whatever reason**.
- It also **might** be because clients are expected to connect via the internet, and there is a NAT router which forwards `29092->KAFKA_HOST:KAFKA_PORT`.

I've seen this article cited all over the place, and I personally I don't think it does anything other than confuse the issue.

For an alternative explanation see [this](https://medium.com/@fintechdevlondon/kafka-listeners-and-advertised-listeners-what-are-they-and-what-do-they-do-9b004e2eb93d) and [this](https://medium.com/@fintechdevlondon/kafka-listeners-and-advertised-listeners-how-do-i-configure-a-kafka-broker-b062de171ce8) blog post.

The key points of clarification are this:

- `listeners` tells the Kafka process which port number and network interface to open a listening socket to. The network interface is determined from the ip address. It must be an ip address which is currently assigned to a network interface on the host.
- `advertised.listeners` **must be set if using the defualt value** from `listeners` **isn't going to work**. This will be required if:
- `listeners` is set to `localhost`
- Clients are expected to connect from beyond a NAT router (eg via an address like `kafka1.example.com:9093` instead of a private ip address
- You are running Kafka in a Docker container (how will a client on an external or local network know what `kafka_docker_1` is?)
- The port number **might** be different if going via NAT or a Docker container host. It depends how the NAT performs port-forwarding, or what ports are mapped by the Docker container host.
- You **may** have more than one listener name defined, with more than one set of config mappings. Commonly used names include `INTERNAL`, `EXTERNAL` `PLAINTEXT`, `CONTROLLER`, `ZOOKEEPER`. Technically these "names" are arbitrary. They only have meaning if they are not included in the security protocol map. (In which case special names like `PLAINTEXT` **do** have meaning.)
- You would define more than one listener if you had for example, a Kafka cluster of multiple brokers where internal traffic was expected to be routed via an internal private network, and where clients were expected to connect from an external network via a NAT enabled router. Each listener needs to have a unique ip address and port number defined in `listeners`, from there, all the other config mappings follow.

---

Some background points which are useful to consider, which helps clarify some of your questions:

- Kafka would usually run as a cluster of brokers, not a single broker system.
- In a single broker system, the `bootstrap.servers` string is just going to contain a single entry. It has to contain the address of "how to contact" the single broker which is in this "cluster" ("cluster" containing a single broker)
- This makes `advertised.listeners` **seemingly** pointless, because it's just going to contain the same address which the client application already has in it's bootstrap servers string
- Now, as part of a multi-broker cluster, the `advertised.listeners` values from **all** brokers will be aggregated together and returned to the client when it connects. This means the client needs minimal knowledge of **one** of the brokers, and from this it can obtain the full list when it connects. For redundancy, you would usually specify 2 or more brokers in the bootstrap string, in case one of them is down when you attempt to connect
- Actually, even in a single broker setup, `advertised.listeners` **may not** be completely pointless. If `listeners` is set to `localhost:9093` that is obviously no good from the client's point of view. `advertised.listeners` will default to the value of `listeners` if it isn't explicitly set. Assuming your value of `listeners` will work when sent back to the client in place of a missing `advertised.listeners`, then you're ok. Otherwise, you must set `advertised.listeners` explicitly.
- `listeners` is just there to tell the Kafka process which network interfaces to open a listening port on.