# Node deployment server

Tags: node.js, server

```
C:\demo\node服务器>node server.js
```

这是我node的最后一行代码

```
server.listen(80,"114.115.140.48")；；；
```

；；

```
events.js:160
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 114.115.140.48:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1245:19)
    at listen (net.js:1294:10)
    at net.js:1404:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)

What shall I do? Wait for your reply Online
```

Comment: This is my last line of code for node
Server.listen (80, 114.115.140.48)

Comment: Please proofread your question both in grammar and format. avoid using Chinese, since the primary language on this site is English.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to search using your keyword like `EADDRNOTAVAIL`

Most likely, the port has been used by other process, use following command to confirm

`netstat -tulpn | grep 80`

If the port is used by some processes, you can find out the process using

`lsof -i :80`

If the process should not occupied port 80, kill it using

`kill -9 <PID>`

[Node.js websocket error "Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276952/node-js-websocket-error-error-listen-eaddrnotavail-error-listen-eaddrnotavail)