# Serving webpack dev server from a specific IP address

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to switch from localhost to a specific IP address, but I keep getting this error:

`listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 192.168.1.139:8000`

**webpack.config.js**

```
devServer: {
    host: '192.168.1.139',
    port: '8000',
    compress: true,
}
```

Comment: Why not use `etc/hosts` mapping? [How to Setup Local DNS Using /etc/hosts File in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-local-dns-using-etc-hosts-file-in-linux/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I need to do it with webpack.

Answer (score 2):

The error you encountered:

```
listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 192.168.1.139:8000
```

Throws due to binding to already used port, it means `8000` is currently being managed eg. from another application ([You must change a port or you must kill a process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26286687)).

For your case of making local IP address binded as `host` it is possible for example via npm/yarn `start`:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --port 8080 --host 192.168.1.139 --content-base ."
```

Assuming your machine's local IP is `192.168.1.139`.

Based on [Snippet from issue #147 `webpack-dev-server`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/147#issuecomment-268878255).

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to map to a differrent ip : You need an entry in your hosts file as well to point that to localhost.
add the below in to your hosts file

`127.0.0.1       192.168.1.139`