# Talking AWS Servers (EC2)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, socket.io

I am trying to get two EC2 instances to talk; but, I am running into a block.  I am not sure what IP address and port to use, and also am wondering if I need to change any of the server/client code now that they aren't talking on the same machine.  Security Groups are allowing inbound traffic on ports 22,80, and 60201.

When I use port 60201, i get EADDRNOTAVAIL.

Here is the config file.

```
Host wmnode
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/wmnode
    HostName 52.4.212.112
Host mvclient
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mvclient
    HostName 107.21.65.254
```

Here is server.js

```
const port = 60201;
const ipAddress = "52.4.212.112"

var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(port, ipAddress);
var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.on('connection', (serverSocket) => {
    console.log('connected to 52.4.212.112');
    serverSocket.on('clientEvent', function (data) {
        console.log('message from the server:', data);
        serverSocket.emit('serverEvent', "thanks for sending '" + data + "'");
    });
});
```

And here is client.js

```
const port = 60201;
const ipAddress = "52.4.212.112";
const url = 'http://' + ipAddress + ':' + port;

var io = require('socket.io-client');

var socket = io(url);

socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.on('serverEvent', function (data) {
        console.log('new message from the server:', data);
    });
    setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit('clientEvent', Math.random());
        console.log('message sent from the client');
    }, 3000);
});
```

[image: Error in its entirity]

Comment: EC2 instances have private IPs and, optionally, public IPs. If these two instances are in the same VPC then you can use private IP addresses to communicate between them. EC2 also has Security Groups (stateful firewalls) so be sure that you have configured Security Groups appropriately to allow your client instance to talk to your server instance.

Comment: @jarmod - Can't you write that into an answer?

Comment: @jfriend00 Hi, I could do that but I think it's likely that there will be more iterations before we come to the real answer. I'm hoping that the OP will engage in the comments so that we can dig a little deeper, and ultimately write up an answer.

Comment: @0TTT0 Please update your question to describe what you are attempting to do, so that we are better able to offer advice. For example, let us know what you have (where is the code running? EC2?), what you have configured so far (eg security group settings?) and what is giving you that error message (eg which line of code?).

Comment: @jarmod I have edited my question to say that I am using EC2 instances and what is the Security Groups configuration.   I can't get the server to listen and continue to get the EADDRNOTAVAIL error

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i have edited my question to include the details you recommended

Comment: SSH servers listen on port 22 so you can't use that. For port 60201, what other process is already listening on that port? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276952/node-js-websocket-error-error-listen-eaddrnotavail-error-listen-eaddrnotavail

Comment: @jarmod Yeah, understand why it doesn't work for port 22, but there is no other process running on 60201 even when i check with ```netstat -tulpn``` ... No matter what port i use i get the EADDRNOTAVAIL error, even when i allow 'all traffic' –

Comment: @jarmod so i got them talking, for some reason the ip address of the listening server was different than the Public IPv4 Address listed on AWS, i found it by using ```ip addr show```.  The client had to connect using the Public IPv4 Address but the server has to listen at a different IP Address.  Why is this?